# Getting value by row number and column number

Tags: crud, google-refine

In custom text facet I want to check value of *previous* row's cell.

I tried `rows[row.index - 1]` with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google refine does not allow you to get the previous row directly. You may wants to have a look at the fill down option but not sure it will help with your project: http://googlerefine.blogspot.ca/2012/03/fill-down-right-and-secure-way.html